# Allow flags when strict transformations are enabled on Cloudinary

Tags: cloudinary

I've enabled *Strict Transformations* on my Cloudinary config.

This restricts what transformations can be delivered by Cloudinary. I have enabled certain width*height transformations to be delivered and that works fine.

The **problem** comes when I want to **retrieve an image with the attachment flag** (fl_attachment). This was working before enabling strict transformations, but after that it isn't retrieving the image.

Is there any way to enable certain flags in Strict Transformations mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'attachment' flag is handled as a part of the transformation. Therefore, if the 'allowed' transformation doesn't include the 'attachment' flag, it will restrict its access. You can create a transformation that includes the 'attachment' flag, and mark it as 'allowed' to allow accessing it. This can be done either interactively using the Dashboard or using our API.

Comment: Thanks! I've found the attachment transformation on https://cloudinary.com/console/transformations and enabled it on the dashboard. It's working!